# When clicking on own comment the share card freezes

Tags: bug, ios-app

I tried to edit my comment (which is not possible) but without being able to tell what each of the icons meant I accidentally pressed the share button.

The card popped up but I couldn’t dismiss it or even select any of the options to then cancel the share.

I took a video but then realised you couldn’t see my finger movements, but I attached an image to where I was talking about:

[image: some telephone screen shot]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone10,4)
- OS Version: Version 13.2.2 (Build 17B102)

Comment: @Laurel yes it is. sorry, i didn’t find it in any of my searches on the app